# Waiting for User Coordinates to use in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to using Vue and trying to collect the lat/long of a user and use the coordinates in other functions within Vue. I am first getting the coordinates and then eventually will use the coordinates in an API, but for now just logging them.

I'm able to display the data, but it's not awaiting for the coordinates before running the `useCoords()` method. What am I doing incorrectly? Do I have await somewhere else in the promise?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ lat }}</p>
    <p>{{ long }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      lat: '',
      long: '',
    }
  },
  methods:{
    async getCoords() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
        this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.long = position.coords.longitude;
      })
    },
    async useCoords(){
        await this.getCoords
        console.log(this.lat);
        console.log(this.long);
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.useCoords()
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue lifecycle methods can be async. You can await your method like this:

Options API

```js
async created() {
    await this.useCoords()
}
```

Composition API

```js
onBeforeMount(async () => {
    await useCoords()
})
```

One note for composition api - there is no "created" hook, so I used onBeforeMount as an example instead. It's a much wider topic than this question entails.